# How to add element in the front of string step by step without converting to a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I know how to add element in the end of string:

```
res = ''
for i in range (0, 5):
    res = res + str(i)
    print(res)
```

> so the result is :01234

but now I want to add element in the front of string, like: 43210
Is there some easy way can add these without converting to list?

I know:

```
l1 = list()
l1.insert(0, str(i))
res = str(l1)
```

but it is more complicate, because my input is str, and output also is str...

Comment: Explain in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just reverse the order of the concatenation:

```
res = ''
for i in range (0, 5):
    res = str(i) + res  # prepend!
print(res)
```

Generally, you should consider using some of the available utils. E.g. `range` can handle the reverse order more easily, and `str.join` is the better option for concatenating more than two strings:

```
res = ''.join(map(str, range(4, -1, -1)))

# res = ''.join(map(str, reversed(range(5))))
```